# Unable to create category in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How to overcome this error in Hybris during category insert

I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have not entered a value for **Identifier** field. It is defined as the unique code of the category. If you see the error message, it mentions *"missing values for [code]"*

While creating a new Category through HMC in Hybris, the following three attributes are necessary to be entered:

- Identifier (the unique code of the category)
- Name (the name of the category)
- Catalog Version (the catalog version the category belongs to)